# In Clion, how can I build the cmake install target with root privileges (sudo)

Tags: installation, cmake, clion

I would like to perform the equivalent of

```
mkdir  build && cd build
cmake ..
sudo cmake --build . --target install
```

from within Clion. The tricky part is to add the "sudo" for the install target. In theory there is an option for this, as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/running-cmake-targets-before-launch.html#0
quote:
"Set the Run with root privileges checkbox to run the target with administrative privileges"
That sounds good, however (on ubuntu, clion installed from the snap store build 2021.2.2
Build #CL-212.5284.51, built on September 16, 2021) this box only appears when the whole application is launched with super user privilege (sudo clion) in which case I have other issues that prevent me from building. Also I find this pretty invasive, having to give privilege to the whole application, when it is only needed for one specific subtask.
How can I tell clion to build a target with super user privilege, without launching clion as root?

Comment: do it in the integrated terminal via commandline and use sudo there? Also, just out of curiosity, why don't you use [`cmake --install <...>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#install-a-project)?

Comment: I mean if you want to do this every single time you develop something, then there is something really weird about your development workflow. If you need to test out how it's being installed then fine, but for that the local install that @user suggested is sufficient.